# Online lecture Videos on Algebraic or Analytic Number Theory or Sieve Theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

I found some lectures on youtube but I need something which starts from the basics.Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: For Algebraic Number Theory,see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/54471/70180).